# Aurora RDS Postgres - Connect over SSL using PgAdmin3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, amazon-aurora

I have created a RDS Aurora PostgresSQL Cluster.
It is accessible publicly and SSL is enabled.
I have completed the entire flow of connecting the instance over SSL using `datagrip`. I would like to do this same thing using PgAdmin3 , but unfortunately I am not able to understand the SSL section under that. In `datagrip` I can directly import `.pem` file, but in PgAdmin3 `.crt` is needed.
Does any body has connected to Aurora PostgresSQL over SSL using PgAdmin3 ?
It will be great if somebody could explain me to how to import the `.pem` file.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the PEM to CRT and use that.

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in your-cert.pem -out your-cert.crt
```